# FIPS Certification for Android & iPhone

Tags: iphone, android, cryptography, fips

Does anyone know the name of the cryptography libraries come with iPhone & Android SDKs ? I don't mean the name of the classes, functions etc. but the name of the provider and/or the library itself. Are they FIPS certified?

Thanks

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/spec/package-descr.html

Comment: Thanks but that's not the answer to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that for Android it's Bouncy Castle and it's not FIPS certified. As for the Apple it's their own implementation and in the process of being FIPS certified according to the NIST's website on the [Modules In Process](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/inprocess.html) list.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there are no fips certified java crypto libraries. So you are stuck with writing a wrapper around a native fips certified fips implementation. Openssl is one that is supported on the mobile devices.

openssl supports both android and iphone. Its worth checking out.